# Flutter - Cannot run mobile app at iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, simulator, macbookpro

I cannot run flutter mobile app at iOS simulator, after put in terminal `fvm flutter run` I just see empty line.

When I run with '-v' it stops at:

```
{
               "ignored" : false,
               "modelCode" : "MacBookPro16,2",
               "simulator" : false,
               "modelName" : "MacBook Pro",
               "operatingSystemVersion" : "14.0 (23A344)",
               "identifier" : "4117DDB0-D402-5B75-9AEC-C5D6BCD3AF8E",
               "platform" : "com.apple.platform.macosx",
               "architecture" : "x86_64h",
               "interface" : "usb",
               "available" : true,
               "name" : "My Mac",
               "modelUTI" : "com.apple.macbookpro-13-retina-four-usb-ports-2020"
             },
             {
               "simulator" : true,
               "operatingSystemVersion" : "17.0 (21A328)",
               "available" : true,
               "platform" : "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator",
               "modelCode" : "iPad13,17",
               "identifier" : "ED28F503-BF45-423F-9517-559398CB41FB",
               "architecture" : "x86_64",
               "modelUTI" : "com.apple.ipad-air5-1",
               "modelName" : "iPad Air (5th generation)",
               "name" : "iPad Air (5th generation)",
               "ignored" : false
             },
             {
               "simulator" : true,
               "operatingSystemVersion" : "17.0 (21A328)",
               "available" : true,
               "platform" : "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator",
               "modelCode" : "iPad13,18",
               "identifier" : "85A83F5E-65BF-4A34-88E1-38F7546DE43D",
               "architecture" : "x86_64",
               "modelUTI" : "com.apple.ipad-10-1",
               "modelName" : "iPad (10th generation)",
               "name" : "iPad (10th generation)",
               "ignored" : false
             }
           ]
```

'flutter doctor -v' shows

```
Could not parse java version from: 

If there is a version please look for an existing bug https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/ and if one does not exist file a new issue.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64, locale en-PL)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Could not determine java version
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
Scanning for devices is taking a long time...
```

Device: Macbook - Sonoma 14.0 - Intel Core i5

Me and my colleges thought that it is connected with i5, but guy who has M1 has the same error.

For now I need to restart MacBook before run app. It is really irritating.

["flutter run -v" stops at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP5ug.png)

["flutter run" stops at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaWEx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

1. open project terminal
2. cd ios
3. pod deintegrate
4. pod repo update
5. pod install

Comment: The error is still occurs

Comment: Can you share photo of error

Comment: I just added links to screenshots at another reply